# When I run `yum install ffmpeg` command to install `ffmpeg` error

Tags: ffmpeg

the following error occurred when installing the ffmpeg library. I found several methods on the Internet, but I couldn't solve it. Post it, I hope everyone can help, thank you very much!

```
[root@localhost asterisk-14.2.0]# yum install ffmpeg
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.cn99.com
 * epel: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn
 * extras: mirrors.cqu.edu.cn
 * linuxtech-release: pkgrepo.linuxtech.net
 * updates: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn
Resolving dependencies
--> Checking transaction
---> Package ffmpeg.x86_64.0.1.1.5-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing dependency libswscale.so.2(LIBSWSCALE_2)(64bit), which is required by package ffmpeg-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing dependency libswresample.so.0(LIBSWRESAMPLE_0)(64bit), which is required by package ffmpeg-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing dependency libavcodec.so.54()(64bit), which is required by package ffmpeg-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64
--> Checking transaction
---> Package ffmpeg-libs_1.1.x86_64.0.1.1.5-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing dependency libgnutls.so.26()(64bit), which is required by package librtmp-2.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Resolve dependencies complete
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
          Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
          Required: libopenjpeg.so.2() (64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
          Required: libcdio_cdda.so.0(CDIO_CDDA_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: librtmp-2.3-3.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
          Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
          Required: libcdio_paranoia.so.0(CDIO_PARANOIA_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
          Required: libcdio_cdda.so.0() (64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
          Required: libcv.so.2.0() (64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
          Required: libgnutls.so.26() (64bit)
Error: Package: librtmp-2.3-3.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
          Required: libgnutls.so.26() (64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
          Required: libcdio_paranoia.so.0() (64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
          Required: libcxcore.so.2.0() (64bit)
 You can try adding --skip-broken option to fix that
 您可以尝试执行：rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem before, I solved it by using the following command, you can try it

`sudo yum --skip-broken update`

`sudo yum clean all`

`sudo yum install`